Dynamic text within div splits word
I have a block of text that's generated randomly from a JSON file, when I use static text, then the code works fine, at the right end of the div, if the word is too long it goes to the next line but in the other case the word gets split
            <div className="test">
                <div className="box">
                    <p className="word">
                        {wordList.map((word, wordIndex) => {
                            const typedWord = typedWords[wordIndex] || "";
                            const isCurrentWord = wordIndex === typedWords.length;
                            const hasWrongChars = typedWord.split("").some((char, index) => char !== word[index]);
                            const isExcessLength = typedWord.length > word.length;
                            const isIncomplete = typedWord.length >= 0 && typedWord.length < word.length && typedWords.includes(typedWord);
                            const shouldHighlightWordRed = hasWrongChars || isExcessLength || isIncomplete;

                            return (
                                <span key={wordIndex}>
                                    {word.split("").map((char, charIndex) => {
                                        let charColor = "#fff";

                                        if (wordIndex < typedWords.length) {
                                            charColor = shouldHighlightWordRed ? "red" : "green";
                                        } else if (isCurrentWord) {
                                            const typedChar = typedChars[charIndex] || "";
                                            charColor = typedChar === char ? "green" : typedChar !== "" ? "red" : "#fff";
                                        }

                                        return (
                                            <span key={charIndex} style={{ color: charColor }}>{char}</span>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                    {'\u00A0'} // space after each word
                                </span>
                            );
                        })}
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: 'row' }}>
                    <input
                        ref={inputRef}
                        value={currentWord}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                </div>

            </div>

CSS:

.test {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 62vh;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    max-width: 58rem;
    width: 58rem;
}

.box {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 149px;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word
}
.box .word {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px 2px;
}
.box .word span {
color: var(--sub-color);
line-height: 2em;
font-weight: 100;
}


With plain text:

With dynamic text:


So what exactly do you want to achieve here? Do you want the word to just not split? Or split in certain ways? Please provide a minimal reproducible code so that we can help you debug. Thanks!

If the word is too long I want the word to move to the next line, but currently it gets split such that first part of the word is on the previous line and the next part on the next line. If I replace code in <p></p> with normal text it works, but in this case it does not

Perhaps this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

You might be using word-break: break-all, follow @Owenn link to know more about it.

@Meet I have updated the question with the CSS, when I added plain text to  it worked as expected but in this case it doesn't

@RohithNambiar I have tried your code with new  provided css and it works fine for me .

@Meet I have updated the question with images of the two cases

The issue was caused by {'\u00A0'} replacing it with {' '} fixed the issue
